# How can I get all the <script> tags out of the way in Chrome inspector?

Tags: meteor, google-chrome-devtools

I'm using Meteor and when I want to inspect the body source of a page I have to scroll past tons of script tags. Is it possible to make it so I can fold those up or get them out of the way somehow?

[image: I want to fold up these script tags]

Comment: You have delete element option in Inspect element

Comment: Wouldn't that remove the script's functionality?

Comment: yes. then drag and drop the scripts in header section

Comment: Is there a way to get them to be in the header section automatically?

Comment: Perhaps another choice instead of trying to change/manipulate Chrome's dev tools is to install an extension in Chrome that does what you are asking? Or use the inspector shortcut (cmd-shift-c) and select and element on the page which would open up the inspector on the correct element?

Comment: Yeah, the element selector helps, but I was more wondering if Meteor could be changed so it doesn't put those scripts in that place. Maybe they have to be there or they won't work.

Comment: Not in the way Meteor keeps package scripts separate for development. You could emulate a production environment with `meteor run --production` which will bundle all your app code into a single script if you are that concerned about it. This changes a few things about your app however, as I would caution you to not rely on this simply for a matter of preference.

Comment: Ok, I see. Not that concerned.

Comment: "Wouldn't that remove the script's functionality?" - No, you can delete the script tag after the script has been loaded. The DOM element isn't needed after that.

Comment: so, is there a jquery command that I could run after the document and all the scripts are loaded that would remove all that from the DOM? Like $('script').remove() or something?

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the scripts in a `<div>` or other generic element. That way it will be collapsed (or collapsible) without affecting functionality.

Comment: I  believe that Meteor is in control of that. Anyway to influence that?

Comment: Search Google. There are some ways to move things around in Meteor. Not sure what works and what doesn't. FTR, searching around it looks like a bad idea to delete the entries as Meteor can rely on them later. Don't do that.